# Consistency of Continuous backup of Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

What would be the consistency of the continuous backup of the write region if the database is using bounded staleness consistency? Will it be equivalent to strong consistent data assuming no failovers happened?

Thanks
Guru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backups made from any secondary region will have data consistency defined by the guarantees provided by the consistency level chosen. In the case of strong consistency, all secondary region backups will have completely consistent data.

Bounded staleness will have data that may have stale or inconsistent data inside the defined staleness window (minimum 300 seconds or 100k writes). Outside of that staleness window the data will be consistent.

Data for the weaker consistency levels will have no guarantees for consistency from backups in secondary regions.

Comment: Thanks. I got this question due to this statement (In strong consistency mode, backup taken in the write region is "---"more up to date"---" when compared to the read regions. Read regions can lag behind due to network or other transient issues) from this below link. [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/continuous-backup-restore-introduction)

Comment: Ok, I made an error here. It seems Continuous Backups are made in every region where the account exists. In that case then backups in secondary regions will lag behind by no more than the defined staleness window. I will update my answer to reflect the correct information.